# Facebook Graph API v1.0 token iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a registered Facebook application that uses FB Graph API in version 1. It has permissions for the following things:

- email
- public_profile
- user_friends

I use it's API key in my iOS application to allow users log in.

I read user token as `[[session accessTokenData] accessToken]];`

However when I use this token in [FB graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I cannot get a list of friends.

The only message I receive are friends that uses this app too so the same when I use api v2.0.

How to get token that allows me to use FB Graph API in version 1?

Comment: If you created your app after 4/30/2014 you can not use API v1.0

Comment: @WizKid "I have a registered Facebook application that uses FB Graph API in version 1."

Comment: I wanted to check because there if you created the app after 4/30/2014 and call graph.facebook.com/v1.0/something it will still be v2.0

Comment: I know, that's not the issue.

Comment: OK. Then it must be that you logged in using api v2.0 the first time.  Because then it doesn't matter if you are using api v1.0 to get friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved that by enabling v1 API compatibility by:

```
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility: YES];
```

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSettings/